# How to insert ID from Jquery UI auto complete

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

i make a jquery autocomplete and its data come from mysql database.now i m facing a small problem in this.

i want to show product name in autocomplete as u see in code below & its working good.but after clicking submit button i want to insert product ID instead of product NAME.Below is my code

```
<?php
require_once "include/config.php";
$sql_product = "select * from tbl_product";
$res_product = mysql_query($sql_product);
?>

<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
         <?php
      while($rs_product = mysql_fetch_array($res_product))
      {
        $prod_name = $rs_product['prod_name'];
      ?>
      "<?php echo $prod_name; ?>" <?php echo ", "; ?>   
      <?php
      }
      ?> 
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>

<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in your values to availableTags source in format like:

```
[{label:"Prod Name 1", value:1}, {label:"Prod Name2", value:2}]
```

Create a hidden input element, like

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidAutoComplete" value="" />
```

And:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function(event, ui) {
        var selectedObj = ui.item;
        $(this).val(selectedObj.label);
        $('input[name="hidAutoComplete"]').val(selectedObj.value);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

TRY ( I assume there is `prod_id` column in your table )

```
var availableTags = [
      <?php
        while($rs_product = mysql_fetch_array($res_product))
        {
           $prod_id[] = $rs_product['prod_id'];                 
        }
        echo  json_encode($prod_id);
      ?> 
    ];
```

#### update

use `json_encode`

Comment: **diEcho** thanks alot for reply, i try it but it's not working